# perl - UNIVERSAL does not export anything

Tags: perl

Hi I am getting the following error when trying to run a perl script:

```
pc:~/Phd/lenovo/programs/vep/scripts/variant_effect_predictor$ perl variant_effect_predictor.pl --help
UNIVERSAL does not export anything at /home/arron/Phd/lenovo/programs/vep/scripts/variant_effect_predictor/Bio/Tree/TreeFunctionsI.pm line 94.
```

where the offending line is:

```
use UNIVERSAL qw(isa)
```

what is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [Universal](https://metacpan.org/pod/UNIVERSAL):

> Previous versions of this documentation suggested using isa as a function to determine the type of a reference:

```
use UNIVERSAL 'isa';

$yes = isa $h, "HASH";
$yes = isa "Foo", "Bar";
```

> The problem is that this code would never call an overridden isa method in any class. Instead, use reftype from Scalar::Util for the first case:

```
use Scalar::Util 'reftype';

$yes = reftype( $h ) eq "HASH";
```

So this method does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Older versions of [UNIVERSAL](http://p3rl.org/UNIVERSAL) say

> You may request the import of three functions (`isa`, `can`, and `VERSION`), but this feature is deprecated and will be removed.
>       Please don't do this in new code.

The latest version just says

> EXPORTS
>
> None.